# Why am I getting an empty arrayList when I call getAllList from MainActivity?

Tags: java, android

This is a custom adapter for a listView and it seems to work fine. The problem is I cant access any of the values (specifically the chronometer). I tried adding the values to an arraylist and creating a method that would return it but it only returns an empty arraylist. I used a toast to check the size of allList as items were added in the getView method and it showed the items being added properly but when I call get allList in MainActivity it returns an empty list.

```
public class TSDataAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<TSData>
{
    private ArrayList<TSData> allList;

    public TSDataAdapter(Context context, int resource, ArrayList<TSData> tsdList)
    {
        super(context, resource, tsdList);
        allList = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        if(convertView == null)
        {
            convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.list_element, parent, false);
        }

        TextView subTitleTextView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.titleTextView);
        TextView countTextView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.countTextView);
        Chronometer chr = convertView.findViewById(R.id.chronometer);

        String subTitle = getItem(position).getSubTitle();
        int count = getItem(position).getCount();
        
        allList.add(new TSData(subTitle, count, new Timer(chr)));

        subTitleTextView.setText(subTitle);
        countTextView.setText(Integer.toString(count));

        return convertView;
    }

    public ArrayList<TSData> getAllList()
    {
        return allList;
    }
}
```

Comment: `allList = new ArrayList<>();` There is your empty list! Replace by `allList = tsdList;`

Comment: `allList.add(new TSData(subTitle......` ? Why are you adding items to the list in getView()? Never saw such. Please post code of getItem().

Comment: Im adding in getView() because that is where the individual chronometers are being created. getItem is part of ArrayAdapter you can see the source code here: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.java

Comment: So if the adapterlist has twenty items and the user scrolls up and down a few times then allList would contain much more. What sense does such have? And you seem to think that we know about chronometers the way you talk.

Comment: You dont need to know about chronometers Im just wondering why when I call getAllList an empty arraylist is returned.

Comment: If you dont show and tell how and where and when you call that function then what do you expect from us?